# Javascript: animate on hover on one specific part

Tags: javascript, onhover

I'm trying to make a `div` `animate slide` when hovering over it.
More specifically I'm making an infobox that will show when hovering over a triangle.

I want to animate ONLY when hovering over the triangle, not when hovering over the transparent space over and under the triangle.
Is this possible to make. 
Here is a jsfiddle of how it looks right now. http://jsfiddle.net/oskkyhj8

I'm new to javascript, and the code may be totally buggy.

Comment: don't set the hover and image on the main div. this is also causing it to repeat across as a background image. you are going to need another div to contain the image and trigger the event or possibly use the psuedo `:after` or `:before` css classes

Comment: here is a rough example http://jsfiddle.net/3qjazzL8/